# Show div with jQuery. css question

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have three divs with `display: inline-block`. In every div i have div with `display: none` when im trying to show hiding div with `$('#div-id').show(1000)` nearest divs 'jump around'
What should i change? I do like to see div under div just draw and the left or right div doesn't change his place.
For example two divs with my problem [there](http://jsfiddle.net/WZCJu/3/) (hide div shows up onchange in the textbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WZCJu/13/

I added this CSS:

```
#amount-div, #specific-div {
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Version without the `width`, you may like it better:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZCJu/15/

Comment: yeap, this is exactly what i need. Just added height to the div. Works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Try using css's `visibility` property instead since it retains the element's position in the flow.

Docs: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp

Example:

```
<div id="herp" style="width: 100px; height: 40px; visibility: hidden;">plarp</div>
<div id="derp" style="width: 100px; height: 40px; visibility: visible;">slarp</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the divs to use float: left; with a specified width you can avoid the "jump around".

See my updated example at: http://jsfiddle.net/WZCJu/12/

I changed the following:

```
<div id="amount-div" style="display:inline-block;">
...
<div id="specific-div" style="display:inline-block;">
```

To use floats with a specified width.

```
<div id="amount-div" style="float:left;width:220px;">
...
<div id="specific-div" style="float:left;width:220px;">
```

I also changed the `<br>` tag which preceeds the submit button so that it will clear the floated divs like so (though, there are better ways of handling that in my opinion):

```
<br style="clear:both">
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `display: none`, the element does not render at all so it doesn't use any space on the rendered web page. I think you might want to use `visibility:hidden` to hide your element but still make the space usage calculation.

EDIT: It appears jQuery method works only on the display style so my answer is not applicable and indeed a fixed offset is necessary to avoid side effects in the page flow.

Answer (score 1):

display none removes the element completely from the document. there wont be any space reserved for it. so when u bring it back(show) it ll rearrange the nearby divs. so try using visibility:hidden which will retain the space but keep the div hidden..

Answer (score 1):

Changing an HTML element from `display: none` to `display: block` or some other value will always cause it to change the flow of other elements around it in the tree. To prevent the DIVs from jumping around, you have a few options. Here are a couple simple ones:

First, you could "pad" the DIV in another DIV with a fixed size. For example:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 2em;">
    <div id="js-amount" style="display: none">    
        <p>You will achieve this goal by:</p>
        <p id="achieved-date"> <p>
        <p id="weekly-limit-amount">Your weekly limit will be decreased by $100</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Secondly, you could use absolute positioning to remove your DIV from the flow of the document:

```
<div id="js-amount" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 50px;">    
    <p>You will achieve this goal by:</p>
    <p id="achieved-date"> <p>
    <p id="weekly-limit-amount">Your weekly limit will be decreased by $100</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set a fixed size for your divs, so when the new one appears, it's constrained with the given side. I updated your JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WZCJu/16/

Have a look at how I constrain the size for your divs in the CSS. To improve layout, I took the liberty to add some styling to the submit button, so the HTML is a little bit modified too.

If you have any trouble understanding my solution, ask some questions.