# browser support attribute rows from textarea

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser, textarea, browser-support

I noticed that browser behave differently for the following

```
<textarea rows="4"></textarea>
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VdL8q/)

In chrome you can resize the `textarea`, but not smaller than 3 rows. However, in firefox the rows attribute seem to be ignored. And to top it all, in IE11 you cannot resize it at all !

Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196424/inconsistent-textarea-handling-in-browsers?rq=1 ?

Comment: that post is about a bottom margin only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding IE, the resize issue occurs because, the re-sizing is done by CSS `resize` property, which is not supported by IE.
This issue can be solved by using [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) plugin:

**Example**

HTML:

```
<textarea type="textarea" id="txtArea" placeholder="enter the message..."></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#txtArea").resizable();
```

CSS:

```
 #txtArea { overflow: hidden; /* for the scrollbars */}
```

And when it comes to Firefox, it always adds an extra line after the textfield. If you want it to have a constant height, you need to use CSS.

So overall there is no out-of-the-box solution, when it comes to the height or any other styles of the textarea in different browsers. So only possible solution left would be to use CSS or Javascript.

If you want to target Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    textarea {
        height: 4em /* or use px to be sure */ ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx for pointing this out! The [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) is also very interesting!!

Comment: You're welcome. This issue has existed for a long time and I don't see a fix coming anytime soon. But then again, it could be a lot worse. :)